# org.hibernate.QueryParameterException:Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 1

Tags: hibernate

I want to perform my select query,

@Query(value=" select * from data o  where  o.id = :id ",nativeQuery = true)

public List findList(Integer id);

Got illegal argument exception,

Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Exception is highlighted in Heading. Will improvise my edits in future. Got the Answer for the issue. @Param was missing.

Answer (score 1):

I have missed @Param ,

@Query(value=" select * from data o where o.id = :id ",nativeQuery = true)
public List findList(**@Param("id")** Integer id);

Adding the above highlighted piece of code, issue is resolved.